# I need to use IHierarchyData and IHierarchicalEnumerable, but they do not exist in .NET Core/.NET 7.0

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0, system.web

I am migrating a project from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 7.0, and some of the class libraries reference IHierarchicalEnumerable and IHierarchyData, which were contained in the namespace System.Web.UI.

I know this reference is not supported in .NET Core, so are there alternatives or how I can use these interfaces please?

I thought maybe using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters would solve the issue, but it does not seem to make a difference.

I also thought maybe using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering might contain the interfaces, but it does not.

Comment: IHierarchyData and IHierarchicalEnumerable are part of ASP.NET Web Forms and are primarily used to handle hierarchical data in controls like TreeView and Menu. What are your needs? Why do you have to use IHierarchyData and IHierarchicalEnumerable in .net core?

Comment: We use them for complex data structures with Grandparent, Parent, children etc, and we sometimes have to fetch child data based on one of the elders. I am not adverse to rewriting the code to build the structures manually, but I'd rather not if I do not have to.

Comment: You can try to manually add `System.Web.UI.dll` to the `Asp.Net Core project`, but please note that because this is a `.net framework dll`, businesses that use this function will have problems when using the Linux platform, and It may cause the application to crash.

Comment: The best way is to redesign the relevant code.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77286183/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.